# Show all results in postgresql?

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

My postgres windows client, upon receiving a query with many results, only shows some of them initially, showing `-- More  --` at the bottom and making you hit "enter" to show each new result line. This is cumbersome and silly. What can I do to make it show me absolutely every result from the start?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you mean `psql` with "my postgres windows client", you can turn off the use of the pager using the [`\pset`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) command:

```
\pset pager off
```

If you want to permanently turn the pager off, add that line to your [`psqlrc.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN92313) file.

Comment: Had no idea it was called the pager. Thanks